# When I get data in the variable from sharedprefs and firestore database It won't displayed on screen

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working on aflutter project where I have a screen called profile in that screen I want to display email, name of a user. Email I am getting from sharedPreference and send that email to firebase to get name from firestore database the problem is when user logged in to the app the name and email is empty no content is displayed on screen I don't know why?

Here is the code:

```
class _ProfileState extends State<Profile> {
  String name = '';
  String email = '';
  String nameFromDatabase = '';
  String emailFromPrefs = '';
  FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  Future<void> getData() async {
    emailFromPrefs = (await sharedPreference().getCred('email'))!;
    nameFromDatabase = (await UserModel().getUser(email))!;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getData();
    setState(() {
      name = nameFromDatabase;
      email = emailFromPrefs;
    });
    print('Email is $email\nName is $name');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Text('User Email is: $email',),
          Text('User Name is: $name'),
          //Logout Button
          MaterialButton(
              child: const Text('Logout'),
              onPressed: () {
                sharedPreference().reset();
                firebaseAuth
                    .signOut()
                    .then((value) => Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                        context,
                        PageRouteBuilder(
                          transitionDuration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
                          transitionsBuilder:
                              (context, animation, animationTime, child) {
                            animation = CurvedAnimation(
                                parent: animation,
                                curve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn);
                            return ScaleTransition(
                              scale: animation,
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              child: child,
                            );
                          },
                          pageBuilder: (context, animation, animationTime) {
                            return LoginOrSignUp();
                          },
                        ),
                        (route) => false));
              },)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `getData` is `future` and you need to `await` for its result, the best approach is use `FutureBuilder` not call `getData` in `initState`. but a work around for it is call setState after data is ready. try this:

```
Future<void> getData() async {
    emailFromPrefs = (await sharedPreference().getCred('email'))!;
    nameFromDatabase = (await UserModel().getUser(email))!;
    setState(() {
       name = nameFromDatabase;
       email = emailFromPrefs;
    });
  }
```

and change your `initState` to this:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getData();
    
    print('Email is $email\nName is $name');
  }
```

**FutureBuilder Approach:**

```
return Scaffold(
  body: FutureBuilder<Map<String, dynamic>>(
         future: getData(),
         builder: (context, snapshot) {
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.waiting:
              return Text('Loading....');
            default:
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
              } else {
                Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data ?? {};
                name = data["name"];
                email = data["email"];
                return Column(
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'User Email is: $email',
                    ),
                    Text('User Name is: $name'),
                    //Logout Button
                    MaterialButton(
                      child: const Text('Logout'),
                      onPressed: () {
                        sharedPreference().reset();
                        firebaseAuth
                            .signOut()
                            .then((value) => Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                                context,
                                PageRouteBuilder(
                                  transitionDuration:
                                      const Duration(seconds: 1),
                                  transitionsBuilder: (context, animation,
                                      animationTime, child) {
                                    animation = CurvedAnimation(
                                        parent: animation,
                                        curve:
                                            Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn);
                                    return ScaleTransition(
                                      scale: animation,
                                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                                      child: child,
                                    );
                                  },
                                  pageBuilder:
                                      (context, animation, animationTime) {
                                    return LoginOrSignUp();
                                  },
                                ),
                                (route) => false));
                      },
                    )
                  ],
                );
              }
          }
        },
      ),
  );
```

also change your `getData` to this:

```
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getData() async {
    emailFromPrefs = (await sharedPreference().getCred('email'))!;
    nameFromDatabase = (await UserModel().getUser(email))!;

    return {"email":emailFromPrefs,"name":nameFromDatabase};
  }
```